# Браузер для java

Tags: java

Подскажите библиотеку-браузер для java, которая может отрабатывать javascript. Или возможность взаимодействия java с существующим браузером. Нужно решить проблему с с открытием сайта и отработкой js, для дальнейшей работы с html кодом.

Comment: Какого рода библиотека нужна? UI-компонент или парсер?

Comment: Или что-то типа selenium?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Chromium Project.

Comment: Selenium WebDriver

Comment: Вы уже задавали этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/857760/204271).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В GUI фреймворке JavaFX есть компонент WebView, который работает как браузер, по сути в нем можно писать десктоп приложения как веб сайты, так же можно и использовать как браузер если дописать функционал в ручную. Но в голом виде все что он может это только запускать js, поддерживать css, открывать ссылки, отображать html код и тому подобное